# json array to c# windows form table

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to build C# Windows Form Application API to communicate with web service. In the API, I have cs file as class file content with functions. There is a function to get response from the web service and output is JSON. I want this class file Json output to another windows form as table.

The class functions are as follows:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<String, object> jsonParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();

jsonParams.Add("within", guest.within);

m_currentCommand = "json=";
m_currentCommand = jsonSer.Serialize(jsonParams);

jsonParams.Clear();

// Create the request and setup for the post.
string strRequest = string.Format("{0}api/s/{1}/stat/guest", Server, SiteName);
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strRequest);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = m_UBNTCookies;

// Set the callback to handle the post of data.
httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(PostCallback), httpWebRequest);

//Wait for the send to complete
m_allDone.WaitOne();

// Now read the reponse and process the data.
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    //DataSet obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText, (typeof(DataTable)));
    //IDictionary<int, ICollection<guestdet>> guests;
    //guests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<int, ICollection<guestdet>>>(responseText);
    //DataTable dtValue = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText, (typeof(DataTable)));
    jsonParams = jsonSer.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, object>>(responseText);

    if (!jsonParams.ContainsKey("data"))
    {
        guest.ERROR = "Error getting guest details";
        return ReturnValue;
    }

     ArrayList list = (ArrayList)jsonParams["data"];


    string strData = string.Empty;

    foreach (Dictionary<String, object> data in list)
    {

        guest.vouchercode = data["voucher_code"].ToString();
        guest.vouchercode = Left(guest.vouchercode, 5) + "-" + Right(guest.vouchercode, 5);
        guest.mac = data["mac"].ToString();
        guest.hostname = data["hostname"].ToString();
        guest.ip = data["ip"].ToString();
        guest.download = data["tx_bytes"].ToString();
        guest.upload = data["rx_bytes"].ToString();

        ReturnValue = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it not give desired output (if yes then please provide examples of what you want and what is happening), does it crash when run (on which line), does it not compile (provide the error messages)?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but anyway, we won't do your work for you. What have you tried already ?

Comment: i want to get above responseText to table array keys as table heading and values as table body. now i can get them to text boxes.